# How to rename Jenkins build status

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins build statuses are SUCCESS, FAILURE , UNSTABLE and ABORTED
I would like to rename UNSTABLE status to something else, i.e. ERROR.
How can it be done without patching Jenkins source code?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @d33tah, My build status  can be or success, or failure ( for product fail) or error( for automation error). Reporting nonstable is not clear for users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and only way is patching the [jenkins](/questions/tagged/jenkins) source code.

Because, Jenkins doesn't have feature of changing status name which are decided by open-source community.

I would rather suggest you to create a plugin as there is not any plugin out there that can solve your problem.

Comment: I would like to avoid patching as I will need to rebuild Jenkins on each new  release. Can some plugin override Result class?
public static final Result UNSTABLE = new Result("UNSTABLE",BallColor.YELLOW,1,true);

Comment: @ilia Then I would suggest you to create plugin and because there is not any plugin for what you are looking.